# Select menu option border none

Tags: css

I am trying to change `select option` border but unable to do that, I have tried it many times but not find the proper solution. I have attached the screen shot .

[image]

```
<head>
  <style>
    select option {
      background:transparent;
      border:0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <select>
    <option>hello</option>
    <option>hello</option>
    <option>hello</option>
    <option>hello</option>
    <option>hello</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

Comment: Not every part of every control can be fully styled. It depends on the browser.

Comment: You can't style how option elements are rendered, that is platform dependent. The best you can do is use a replacement widget that replicates select element functionality using other elements.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The dropdown of a select is part of what's called the [ShadowDOM](http://glazkov.com/2011/01/14/what-the-heck-is-shadow-dom/). In the current CSS specs, level 3, there's no way to target most ShadowDOM elements. You can read the  specs on the ShadowDOM [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/shadow-dom/), though there's not much in there regarding what you want.

Chrome has a few proprietary selectors to change *some* shadowDOM elements, but not all. Firefox has even fewer (as far as I know), and Opera has none. IE is probably just as bad or worse.

Your best bet with compatibility in mind is to use a Jquery plugin to mimic the select using other HTML elements if you really want to style it. [Here's a neat one](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/).

Answer (score 1):

As far as I have understood this is not possible, are properties that depend on each browser, no questions past that may make things a little clearer.

Greetings.

Perhaps this may be of help:

[How to style a <select> dropdown with CSS only without JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895476/how-to-style-a-select-dropdown-with-css-only-without-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

**The short answer**:

**THIS CAN'T BE DONE WITH A `select` ELEMENT**

**Possible solution**:

Use any UI library ([bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/dropdowns/), [jquery UI](https://jqueryui.com/selectmenu/), or [any other](https://www.sitepoint.com/13-jquery-selectboxdrop-down-plugins/)) to make a custom select-like element, that you can style as you wish (they all generate a control using other, customization-friendly elements like `ul`, `li`, `div`....)