# How to get rid of the blue border that surrounds the entire options list

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to do is if i click the select box and the dropdown list show the blue border-color of the dropdown list will be remove.

testing link: http://jsfiddle.net/5kcsn/320/

script:

```
$("input, select, textarea, form, button").css("outline", "none");
$("input, select, textarea, form, button").css("box-shadow", "none");
```

css:

```
option:focus{
    background-color:#FFF;
    outline:none;
    border:none;
    box-shadow:none;
}
```

Comment: What browser? There's no blue border for me in Chrome or FF

Comment: @BootstrapThemer Same with Safari. So that leaves IE... or maybe Netscape if everyone's feeling a little weird.

Comment: @BootstrapThemer chrome

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it looks like there is not a way to remove it. Please see this answer: [Select menu option border none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056300/select-menu-option-border-none)

Answer (score 0):

Some styles are built in the browser you can't edit them with css what else you can do is implement javascript to make your own elements like them also there are various javascript plugins that can help you!
Try [this](http://plugins.jquery.com/?s=select%20menu) search for jQuery Plugins

Answer (score 0):

You can try using customized drop downs. In this case the drop down  is replaced by  or

and the select is hidden beneath it. Then they can be customized as per our liking.

Reference URL: http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomDropDownListStyling/