# How to remove blue borders on opened select

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to stylizate option in select.

**HTML**:

```
<select class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Kurioi pozicijoi norėtumėte dirbti?</option>
    <option value="two">Programavimo</option>
    <option value="three">Dizainerio</option>
    <option value="four">Redaktorio</option>
    <option value="five">Moderatorio</option>
</select>
```

**CSS:**

```
 #toggle select.form-control:focus {
    border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px !important;
 }

 #toggle select.form-control option {
    background-color: #febe10 !important;
    color: #FFF;
    padding: 3px;
    outline: 0;
    font-weight: 500;
    border:0px;
    outline: 0px;
 }
```

But I'm still getting blue borders on chrome:

[image]

**Question: How to remove these blue borders?**

```css
#toggle select.form-control:focus {
        border-radius: 2px 2px 0px 0px !important;
     }

     #toggle select.form-control option {
        background-color: #febe10 !important;
        color: #FFF;
        padding: 3px;
        outline: 0;
        font-weight: 500;
        border:0px;
        outline: 0px;
     }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<select class="form-control">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Kurioi pozicijoi norėtumėte dirbti?</option>
    <option value="two">Programavimo</option>
    <option value="three">Dizainerio</option>
    <option value="four">Redaktorio</option>
    <option value="five">Moderatorio</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Your image is a little bit big (white space).

Comment: did you try ```border: 0;``` instead of ```border:0px;``` ? To remove things via CSS you normally don't provide any units.

Comment: @actc It is basically the same. The unit is not required, but it doesn't hurt.

Comment: @Arendax yes sorry for that.

Comment: @Arendax I experienced some weird behaviors so we usually omit units

Comment: @actc same. Make me sick chrome. 3hours still no mind how to remove.

Comment: try outline:none;

Comment: @ромМакаров: Can you upload it on JSfiddle?

Comment: check this one https://jsfiddle.net/b9fa5ows/1/

Comment: I¨m quite sure that select elements are controlled by the OS and are therefore not able to be styled without select replacement techniques.

Comment: @Leothelion same with "outline:none;"

Comment: Check my fiddle. use in select tag rather then your css.

Comment: Have you tried `outline:0` on the parent, rather than on the options?

Comment: Oops, I should have marked that as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056300/select-menu-option-border-none instead.