# HTML/CSS - remove/recolor border of dropdown options

Tags: html, css

```css
select {
  width: 300px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;  
  padding-right: 30px;
  display:block;
  color: #999;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #757575;
}
*:focus {
outline: #757575;
}
 
select:focus {outline:0;}
```

```html
<select class="weekselection">
  <option value="" disabled selected>Choose the weekday</option>
  <option value="0">Monday</option>
  <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
  <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
  <option value="3">Thursday</option>
  <option value="4">Friday</option>
  <option value="5">Saturday</option>
  <option value="6">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

I'd like to remove or change the color of my dropdown menu:[image]

That blue thing marked by the arrow. I've tried combinations of

```
select {
  border: none;
}

*:focus {
outline: #757575;
}

select:focus {outline:0;}
```

But it still stays there. How can I remove it? Thank you!

HTML:

```
<select class="weekselection">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Choose the weekday</option>
    <option value="0">Monday</option>
    <option value="1">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="2">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="3">Thursday</option>
    <option value="4">Friday</option>
    <option value="5">Saturday</option>
    <option value="6">Sunday</option>
</select>
```

Comment: try to "border:0 !important"

Comment: But the `select` element applies to the button you press to view the dropdown elements, and that works ("Choose the weekday" doesn't have any borders). I think there's some other tag I'm supposed to use for the `<option>` elements maybe.

Comment: the output looks like a custom `Select` tag plugin. Try to upload your working code or link it somewhere. If this is the exact output you are getting, then I don't think `styling` `SELECT` tag could help. it may be some other element getting rendered due to some 3rdparty js

Comment: There is no custom plugins, just base html

Comment: can you share url

Comment: Check the snippet I've added.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056300/select-menu-option-border-none

Comment: Support for styling of select boxes and their options is quite bad and inconsistent among browsers. If you want to spare yourself frustration and time; use a plugin of some sort, or write a little javascript.

Comment: I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the rendered HTML using developer tools of your browser? You may see that there is a rule somewhere in your CSS that overwrites this one or there may be some js that add inline style. Note that css rules are executed top bottom and the last overwrites the previous. The inline style is rendered last

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The answer is: you can't because css can't modify options' style.

But you can use a list and make it act like a dropdown to be free to stylize it:

### Demo

```js
$("ul li").slideUp();
$("label").click(function () {
    $("ul li").slideToggle();
});
$("ul li").click(function () {
    $("label").text($(this).text());
    $("ul li").slideToggle();
});
```

```css
ul {
  display: table;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>One</label>
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to another question and I quote:

The dropdown of a select is part of what's called the ShadowDOM. In the current CSS specs, level 3, there's no way to target most ShadowDOM elements. You can read the specs on the ShadowDOM here, though there's not much in there regarding what you want.

Chrome has a few proprietary selectors to change some shadowDOM elements, but not all. Firefox has even fewer (as far as I know), and Opera has none. IE is probably just as bad or worse.

Your best bet with compatibility in mind is to use a Jquery plugin to mimic the select using other HTML elements if you really want to style it. Here's a neat one.

[Select menu option border none](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14056300/select-menu-option-border-none)

Answer (score -4):

I think "!important" will help you to solve the problem.

```
select {
     border: none !important;
     }
```

Comment: But the select element applies to the button you press to view the dropdown elements, and that works ("Choose the weekday" doesn't have any borders). I think there's some other tag I'm supposed to use for the <option> elements maybe.

Comment: If you will provide me fiddle I can do some work on it and get good solution.
I try to run your code but its running without border.

Comment: No, it's not. The select element is borderless, but the items that are dropped down (see arrow on picture on my post) has a blue border.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_button

Comment: This doesn't quite apply, since it's using a `div`with links. I'm using `select` with `option`s. I need to change the `value`, not just send the user to some other page.

Comment: Replace your code on that link and see the difference and still notgetting solution then provide me fiddle.