# Change style of dropdown list

Tags: css, arrays, angular, angularjs, styles

Anyone has any solution to remove borders oon options in a dropdown list.
Im about to create this view:
[image]

The code i tried is below

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jfauvw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

Saw lots of codes that use Jquery but this is not possible in my project.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove border of drop down list : CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639638/how-to-remove-border-of-drop-down-list-css)

Comment: Thas a pretty old question and doesnt work for my case. Thought has some more updates around. I saw before for sure. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: It is still true today, but there is a solution with js [HTML/CSS - remove/recolor border of dropdown options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42550029/html-css-remove-recolor-border-of-dropdown-options)